# Trouble with inputting a 2D array to subsequently sort and print?

Tags: python, list, sorting, input, 2d

I am struggling with this problem, and I would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

My problem is this:  I need to get 3 inputs from the user to begin.  I have to first get the dimensions (M and N) of my 2D list from the user.  Then I read in the user input for each row of the matrix one line at a time. The last input is which  element of the list I want to sort by.  If each input row was 4 ints long, I may want to sort it by the 2nd int.

Next, in my actual function, I have to sort this and print it out.

I have tried to use a nested for loop to initialize the 2d array.  I
suspect something may be going wrong here, but I'm not sure.  I think
I've figure out how to sort it. However, I'm getting an error in my
print function that says invalid syntax.  But the syntax seems right to
me.

Below is my code:

```
n,m = map(int,raw_input().split())
my_list = []
for x in range(n):
    row=[]
    for y in range(m):
        row.append(list(map(int,raw_input())))
    my_list.append(row)

k = int(raw_input())

sorted_list=sorted(my_list,key=lambda x:x[k])

for row in sorted_list:
    for val in row:
        print '{:4}'.format(val),
    print
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What version of python are you using? Your code works fine in 2, but in 3 you need parenthesis around the input of the print, as well as some other changes.

Comment: What part of the problem are you struggling with?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this what you want: (I have printed several strings so that it becomes clear which parts are doing what.)

And the inserted dimension has not been maintained intentionally to make it clear that we are not doing any kind of validation in the following code.

```
print 'Enter dimension col X row:'
col, row = map(int, raw_input().split())
print 'col: ' + str(col) + '\trow: ' + str(row)

my_list = []
for r in range(row):
    print 'Insert row: ' + str(r)
    my_list.append(map(int, raw_input().split()))
print 'You have inserted: '
print(my_list)

print 'Position by which the array to be sorted: '
index = int(raw_input())
sorted_list = sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: x[index])
print 'Sorted by: index ' + str(index)
print sorted_list


# Checking if all row has >= 4 elements
def elem_more_then_4(my_2d_array):
    for row in my_2d_array:
        if len(row) < 4:
            return False
    return True


if elem_more_then_4(my_list):
    sorted_list_ = sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: x[1])
    print 'Sorted by 2nd element: '
    print sorted_list_
```

Interaction in the console:

```
Enter dimension col X row:
5 4
col: 5  row: 4
Insert row: 0
1 2 1 5 4
Insert row: 1
5 1 24 3
Insert row: 2
3 2 1 4 2
Insert row: 3
5 2 1 4 3
You have inserted: 
[[1, 2, 1, 5, 4], [5, 1, 24, 3], [3, 2, 1, 4, 2], [5, 2, 1, 4, 3]]
Position by which the array to be sorted: 
3
Sorted by: index 3
[[5, 1, 24, 3], [3, 2, 1, 4, 2], [5, 2, 1, 4, 3], [1, 2, 1, 5, 4]]
Sorted by 2nd element: 
[[5, 1, 24, 3], [1, 2, 1, 5, 4], [3, 2, 1, 4, 2], [5, 2, 1, 4, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with what @Sam Craig commented. You need parenthesis after print in Python 3.x to solve the syntax error problem.

Another problem it seems to me is, you're mapping your array into a higher dimension matrix than expected. You might simply want to use row.append(int(input())) instead of row.append(list(map(int,raw_input())))

```
    n,m = map(int,input().split())
    my_list = []
    for x in range(n):
        row=[]
        for y in range(m):
            row.append(int(input()))
        my_list.append(row)

    k = int(input())

    sorted_list=sorted(my_list,key=lambda x:x[k])

    for row in sorted_list:
        for val in row:
            print('{:4}'.format(val))
    print
```

Hope it helps.